# AngularJS refresh doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got a simple 2 sections that I want to be old and new. Once new is done and socket is being invoked old = new and new should be empty. The thing is everything keeps still adding into upper (new) section.
The last socket is responsible for managing this.

Controller :

```
.controller('DepositsCtrl', function ($scope, mySocket) {
        $scope.deposits = [];
        $scope.olddeposits = [];
        $scope.winnerSteamName = "";
        $scope.roundValue = 0;
        $scope.winnerChance = 0;
        $scope.avatarWinner = "";

        mySocket.on('sendDepositIO', function(steamIdIO, itemCountIO, depositValueIO, avatarIO, steamNameIO) {
            $scope.deposits.push({
                steamId: steamIdIO,
                itemCount: itemCountIO,
                depositValue: depositValueIO,
                avatar: avatarIO,
                steamName: steamNameIO
            })
        });

        mySocket.on('newConnection', function (depositsInRound, olddepositsInRound) {
            $scope.deposits = depositsInRound;
            $scope.olddeposits = olddepositsInRound;
        });

        mySocket.on('newRoundDeposit', function () {
            $scope.olddeposits = $scope.deposits;
            $scope.deposits = [];
        });
```

Html :

```
<div ng-controller="DepositsCtrl">
            <h2>Deposits</h2>
            <hr class="line-under">
            <section class="round section">
                <ul>
                    <li class="li-deposit" ng-repeat="deposit in deposits | orderBy:'-'">
                        <div class="deposit-person"><img class="small-avatar" ng-src="{{deposit.avatar}}" /> <span class="name">{{deposit.steamName}}</span> </div>
                        <div class="deposit-items">{{deposit.itemCount}} items</div>
                        <div class="deposit-value">{{deposit.depositValue}}$</div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <hr class="line-under">
                        <h3 class="new-round text-center">New Round  <i class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-lg"></i></h3>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
            <section class="round section">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="text-center center-block">
                            <img class="small-avatar" ng-src="{{avatarWinner}}" /><span>{{winnerSteamName}} has won {{roundValue}} with {{winnerChance}}% chance !</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li-deposit" ng-repeat="olddeposit in olddeposits | orderBy:'-'">
                        <div class="deposit-person"><img class="small-avatar" ng-src="{{olddeposit.avatar}}" /> <span class="name">{{olddeposit.steamName}}</span> </div>
                        <div class="deposit-items">{{olddeposit.itemCount}} items</div>
                        <div class="deposit-value">{{olddeposit.depositValue}}$</div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <hr class="line-under">
                        <h3 class="new-round text-center">Previous Round  <i class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-lg"></i></h3>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at your code and reading the discussion with Leandro I am wondering.

Are you really sure that 'newRoundDeposit' is emitted and catched?

Sorry if this is a silly question, but for me, your coding looks correct.

Comment: There are no stupid questions and this one is definitely not one of them.
I was emitting newRoundDeposits instead of newRoundsDeposit. simply missing "s" at the end. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are objects and objects are assigned by reference, so when you do $scope.olddeposits = $scope.deposits, you are assigning the reference stored in deposits to olddeposits.

Try `$scope.olddeposits = angular.copy($scope.deposits);` and see what happens.

Comment: Haven't fixed anything unfortunately

Comment: What you mean when you say everything keeps adding in new? In sendDepositIO you are still adding things into deposits so that section will be updated.

Comment: Yes but I want this section to be cleared and moved to olddeposits when newRoundDeposit event is called.

Comment: Can you show my socket service? Are you using any library that runs the digest cycle when an event comes? If not you won't see the changes reflected in the view. Wrap the code in the events in a $timeout and check what happens.

Comment: Did you do the test with timeout?

Comment: Try using controller as syntax, and assigning the value to the controller instance. As a rule you should always bind to something dot something.